# How to get chart size (without labels) with chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

Now i have this chart:
https://codepen.io/UnluckySerivelha/pen/BawpPYv

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('graph').getContext('2d');

        var bar_ctx = document.getElementById('graph').getContext('2d');

        x=["14 Dec","15 Dec"];
        y1={"14 Dec":0,"15 Dec":0,};
        y2={"14 Dec":0,"15 Dec":0,};
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: x,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Всего за день',
                        data: y1
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Будет начислено по вкладам',
                        data: y2,
                    },
                ]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        ticks: {
                            callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                return '$ ' + value;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                },
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false
            },
        });
```

I want to add background image for chart area, but not for labels. I know how to add background image, but don't know how to get size of chart area without labels for assignment size and position of image. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `chartArea` property that is available in the chart context. This property has the width and height of the area where the chart itself is being drawn.

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);

console.log('height: ', chart.chartArea.height);
console.log('width: ', chart.chartArea.width)
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Your own code with the background colored pink: https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/OJxWoPe

Official example on using an image as background: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/canvas-background.html#image